# Rendering Chinese/UTF8 characters in MySQL Select using PuTTY & commandline client

Tags: mysql, utf-8, fonts

Is there any good, straightforward way to connect to a MySQL database using MySQL's normal commandline client while connected using PuTTY and get it to render UTF8 fields that include non-Western characters properly?

My tables use UTF8 encoding, and in normal use the values come from an Android app and are displayed by an Android app. The problem is that occasionally, Things Go Wrong, and when they do, it's almost impossible for me to figure out what's going on because MySQL's commandline client forcibly casts UTF8 values to (what appears to be) ISO-8859-1 (ie, quasi-random gibberish when shown on the screen). For what it's worth, Toad for MySQL (both free and beta) seem to mangle UTF8 output the same way.

On a semi-related note, my favorite monospaced font is Andale Mono (yeah, I really like the forcibly-disambiguated 0/O and 1/l characters). I'm pretty sure it doesn't include CJK characters. Is there any (free) utility that can be used to rip the lower 127 or 256 characters from one Truetype font (like Andale Mono), and create a new Truetype font based on some UTF8 CJK Truetype font that replaces the lower 127 or 256 characters with the font data ripped from Andale Mono?

Answer (score 3):

First you should make sure that your console encoding is set to UTF-8.
Using PuTTY you need to set the charset dropdown in "Window" > "Translation" to UTF-8

Second MySQL distincts the data charset and the connection charset.
When your data is UTF-8 encoded but your connection charset is set to e.g. "ISO-8859-1" MySQL will automatically convert the output.

The easiest way to set the charsets permanently is to update your client my.cnf with the following:

```
[client]
default-character-set=utf8
```

Detailed information about the connection charset you can find here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-connection.html

When using the MySQL API functions ( PHP client e.g. ) you can set the connection charset by sending the query

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

Various implementations of the MySQL API also support setting the charset directly.
e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Comment: Hmmm. No luck, yet, but I think it's the font I'm using. As luck would have it, Andale Mono apparently DOES exist with pretty much the entire UTF8 character set (including Chinese), but for some crazy reason, there doesn't appear to be any straightforward way to actually PURCHASE it as an end user. It's only officially available as an add-on to SAP. And the one duospaced font Monotype DOES sell as a retail product that includes the full UTF8 character set doesn't give any clue in the info page whether it disambiguates O/0 and l/1. Argh.

Comment: By the way, for anybody who's never seen the term 'duospace', it's a (recent?) variant of monospacing that attempts to reconcile the fact that Chinese characters are supposed to fill a square bounding box, but Roman/Cyrillic/Greek letters are rectangular. Basically, Duospaced fonts split the difference by making Chinese characters exactly twice as wide as Roman/Cyrillic/Greek letters (doing similar gymnastics with Japanese, Korean, Arabic, Hebrew, etc, as appropriate).