# why in remote server cannot input Chinese character in mysql command line but local is ok

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

In my local machine(Mac OS) iTerm2 terminal, I could login remote mysql server and input `Chinese` character successfully

```
➜  ~ mysql -h remote_ip  -u username -p foo --safe-updates

mysql> select '你好';
+--------+
| 你好   |
+--------+
| 你好   |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

then I login a remote server by ssh

```
➜  ~ ssh root@remote_ip
```

and login the same mysql server

```
root@qa-web:~# mysql -h remote_ip  -u username -p foo --safe-updates

mysql> select '
```

but this time I cannot input Chinese character in command line, after inputting they are disappeared immediately.

Why is so?

---

#### Additional information

In above second case

```
mysql> status
...
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
```

---

My machine Mac OS

```
➜  ~ locale
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Remote Server

```
root@hg:~# locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

root@hg:~# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
POSIX
```

Copy this sql(`select 'hello','你好';`) from Atom to Mysql command line, and the effect is

```
mysql> select 'hello','';
+-------+--+
| hello |  |
+-------+--+
| hello |  |
+-------+--+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

---

Locale

```
➜  ~ 你好
zsh: command not found: 你好
```

Remote

```
root@hg:~# 你好
-bash: $'\344\275\240\345\245\275': command not found
```

Answer (score 2):

try starting mysql with `mysql --default-character-set=utf8`
This forces the character_set_client, character_set_connection and character_set_results variables to be UTF8.

Source: [MySQL command line formatting with UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787824/mysql-command-line-formatting-with-utf8)

Of course if you are using a chinese specific charset, start it with that. Like GB (gb18030) charsets for example.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your way: `mysql --default-character-set=utf8 -h remote_ip  -u username -p foo --safe-updates`. It does not work.

Comment: could it also be terminal charset problem or ssh charset problem?

Comment: ive found this also maybe this is of help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028750/rendering-chinese-utf8-characters-in-mysql-select-using-putty-commandline-clie

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows with `cmd`, then...

The command "chcp" controls the "code page". `chcp 65001` provides utf8, but it needs a special charset installed, too. [some code pages](http://www.computerhope.com/chcphlp.htm)

To set the font in the console window: Right-click on the title of the window → Properties → Font → pick Lucida Console

Comment: The OP says they're using iTerm on Mac

Comment: "Multi-Lingual

iTerm2 features excellent internationalization support, including support for Unicode combining marks, double-width characters, and all Unicode planes."

Comment: ? Your answer relates to Windows

Answer (score 0):

On Unix systems you need to make sure your locale matches your terminal emulation. Programs, like the MySQL shell, uses the locale value to determine what encoding to write to the terminal in.

On Mac, the default locale is usually UTF-8 based, which matches the default iTerm profile.

When you remote shell, you also need to make sure the remote locale matches your terminal. If the remote server is non-mac then it's more likely that the locale is not UTF8 based.

When you remote shell, get the locale in play

```
locale
```

To work with the Mac defaults, it needs to be  `*.utf-8`. For example:

```
en_gb.utf-8
```

If it's not then you must change it, at least temporarily. See what locales are available:

```
locale -a
```

Find an appropriate locale then set the LANG environment variable:

```
export LANG=en_gb.utf-8
```

Now you can run mysql and get the correct results.

Comment: Thanks!  please see my additional info in the post.

Comment: and very strange, in remote server most have double quotes("),  but some not

Comment: Ok, `LANG` is not set to a valid value. You need to do `export LANG="en_US.utf8"`

Comment: thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45860094/2227031，we need to update locale